# SQLite usage from activity and service

Tags: android, sqlite

I have created a databaseprovider class which uses single instance of db object. Object is created in main activity and closed onDestroy method. This seems ok (but get some errors such as: db already closed or db is not open on some users devices that I cannot simulate).

I want to add a service to the application for the content download and this service can run with  scheduler which make me think about single instance of db object will not work. Should I use another object for the service, will it result consistency problems? Can you kindly advice what would be the best way?

### Databaseprovider class exm:

```
public class DatabaseProvider {
private static DatabaseHelper helperWriter;
public static SQLiteDatabase db_global;
public DatabaseProvider(Context c) {
    helperWriter = DatabaseHelper.getHelper(c, true);
}

private static SQLiteDatabase getDB() {     

    if(db_global == null)           
        db_global = helperWriter.getWritableDatabase();
    else if(!db_global.isOpen()) {
        try {
            db_global.close();
        }
        catch(Exception ex) {
            ex.printStackTrace();
        }
        db_global = helperWriter.getWritableDatabase();
    }

    return db_global;
}

public String GetVersion() {
    SQLiteDatabase db = getDB();
    Cursor c = db.query(DatabaseHelper.PARAMETER_TABLE_NAME, new String[] {"VALUE"}, "KEY='Version'", null, null,null,null);
    String version = "";
    if(c.moveToNext())
    {
        version = c.getString(0);           
    }
    else
        version = "0";
    c.close();

    return version;
}

public long UpdateVersion(String value) {
    ContentValues initialValues = new ContentValues();
    initialValues.put(DatabaseHelper.PARAMETER_COLUMN_VALUE, value);
    SQLiteDatabase db = getDB();   
    long r = db.update(DatabaseHelper.PARAMETER_TABLE_NAME, initialValues, "KEY='Version'", null);
    if(r <= 0)
        r = helperWriter.AddParameter(db, "Version", value);
    //db.close();   
    return r;
}   

public void CloseDB() {
    if (db_global != null)
        db_global.close();
    db_global = null;
    helperWriter.close();
}
 }
```

---

Comment: Take a look at this blog post, and the SO question it refers back to - http://kagii.com/mobile

Comment: Thanks Simon, I will check that.

Answer (score 1):

Not sure if this will help, but...

you can't rely on onDestroy() in case the app crashes. Android may also keep your app in RAM, even if you exit it. Also, your main activity may get destroyed while the app is getting used if you are on a subactivity. It can also get recreated.

Sometimes it's better to have calls that open the DB, does stuff to it, and then closes it within the same function. If you are using a service, it may actually help things. I also am not sure if you should have a situation where a DB can be opened and/or accessed from a variety to different places at once without some management code

Comment: Thanks @Joe. Yes you are right; it is not guaranteed that onDestroy() will be called. But after got many problems about db and researches on internet, I tried single instance and minimized the problems. I tried your suggestion to see if it is ok with new SDK. The problem is sometimes i get "database is not open". The scenario is: Start an activity, then update content and some db operations in AsyncTask. While update is in progress go back and start the same activity again. Probably the previous operation closes db and the new one tried to access to the closed db.

Answer (score 0):

I see a couple questions:

A)

> (but get some errors such as: db already closed or db is not open on some users devices that I cannot simulate). 
>   ...
>   Start an activity, then update content and some db operations in AsyncTask. While update is in progress go back and start the same activity again.

To work around these errors have you considered using a `[Loader][1]`?  It's a callback based framework around `ContentProvider`s.

---

B)

> add a service to the application for the content download and this service can run with scheduler which make me think about single instance of db object will not work. Should I use another object for the service, will it result consistency problems?

[This post by @commonsware](http://www.androidguys.com/2009/09/09/diamonds-are-forever-services-are-not/) from this website, suggests not to use `Service` for long running tasks.  Instead the `AlarmManager` is suggested.  I've only worked with short running services (for audio IO) myself.